# what is the issue with this rmarkdown parser error

Tags: r, r-markdown

For whatever reason `rmarkdown::render` creates an error with this markdown file: I have tried to play around with the file, but the error is always the same `line 7, column 1` even if I add dummy lines. This is very surprising...

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Robert"
date: 2016-11-21
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
  plot(1:3, 1:3)
```
````

> Error in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) :    Parser error:
>   while parsing a block mapping at line 1, column 1did not find expected
>   key at line 7, column 1

Comment: i ran this with `knitr` and it worked fine

Comment: It works fine for me too, can you provide your `sessionInfo()`. If it doesn't already include it, could you add what version of `knitr` and `rmarkdown` you're using.

Comment: pretty sure it's useless now but adding four backticks and markdown previous to first block solved the problem, see https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-in-rmarkdown-knit-yaml/21833/10